# Android Eclipse, Dropbox, Windows and Linux

Tags: android, windows, linux, eclipse

I'm using my Dropbox folder to store my Eclipse workspace in (instant back ups) but want to develop on both Linux and Windows. (I think) the workspace file stores the location of the Android SDK which is different on both machines /home/android... and c:\android.

Is there any way of developing on Windows one minute and Linux the next? (the issue is the directory of the Android SDk.

thanks

Comment: I recommend having the workspace outside of Dropbox, and then **not** having the individual Projects inside the workspace. This means some additional clicks because you have to set the path of each new project and then import it on the other computer, but I've never had much success sharing the workspace via Dropbox. That's why I not simply put the projects in Dropbox, but let each computer have it's own workspace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution is source version control, checkout a [comparison table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Aye, this is the best, most hassle-free way to go. I use Windows and Linux simultaneously on different PCs and it works perfectly.

Comment: I use both :-) I have Dropbox for sharing accross multiple computers and instant backup, and Mercurial-repositories for version control. I prefer it that way, because I'm not forced to make a commit just because I switch computers.

Comment: You can have a working branch that you commit before every workstation switch, and merge to trunk when it makes sense. Also, I would prefer rsync over Dropbox

Comment: I was thinking of using Dropbox for small projects, but I like the idea of using something like [Github](http://github.com) and Egit for Eclipse when I have more complex projects.

Answer (score 5):

I use Dropbox for this two, I switch between Windows, Mac and Linux.  This is how I do it:

1. Put the Windows version in the Dropbox
2. Create a new Android Project with the same name in Linux somewhere other than Dropbox
3. Delete the assets, res and src folders and replace them with softlinks to the ones in Dropbox

This way each OS has it's own project files, but anytime you update a resource or code file it will update on all OS's.